# Do the molex connectors on a 2x molex to 6 pin PCI connector need to be on different leads?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

My video card came with an adaptor like this

[image]

Its 2 gaptoothed male molex connectors (with horribly non standard colour coding) connected to a 6 pin PCI-e power connector. I got it with a zotac video card, but I'm pondering using it to test a second video card, possibly with much jerryrigging.

Generally most PSUs have more than one daisychained 'runs' of molex connectors with 3 or more connectors on them. Should each of the male connectors on one of these be put on different runs or can I just stick them on the same one?

Comment: I'd be inclined to say, it depends on what power it will be pulling, compared to what you can feed from one 12v rail. If in doubt, use 2 rails. [or, more cynically... try one; if it crashes, try 2 ;)

Comment: Assuming they are separate rails. A video card would be pulling considerably more power, thus current than a HDD I'd guess. That's assuming that the setup I have can handle the load, and I can find some way to fully tax a powerful main video card, and a decent secondary card doing phyx or doing that neat mixed card setup dx12 promises..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would separate them because I don't know what else is on those wires. Check the gauge wire on your power supply. The bigger,in diameter, the wire the smaller the gauge. 12 gauge wire is rated for 20A (240w max) and 14 for 15A (or 180w max). If for some reason you got 16 gauge(because they wanted to save money) wire then definitely separate them.  Most power supplies offer 50A+ at 12 volts so you shouldn't overdraw individual runs.

Comment: 50A @12v is going some. idk many supplies that can do that

Comment: @Tetsujin clearly we don't shop in the same class.  Look at 600W and above PSU.  I like 800W PSU.

Comment: Nothing else in my case. And its a quality modular PSU, though I think I'd be skating on the edge of not having enough power.

Comment: The 6-pin only 75W max so 2x is 150w.  You only had 30w left,maybe (because a few GPU overdraw the max a little), use a different run for everything else.  The 8 pin is 150w max.